# TesserActJS error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

Using the Tesseract NPM package. And getting the following error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of null

I know a UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning is a promise which throws an error and doesn't have a `.catch()` method. This is my code (also uses the npm sharp package)

```
function processText() {

    sharp('./screenshot.png')
        .extract({ left: 40, top: 585, width: 405, height: 70 })
        .resize({ height: 210 })
        .toFile(`./text.png`, function (err) {
            worker
                .recognize('./text.png')
                .then(({ text }) => {
                    console.log(text) 
                    worker.terminate();
                })

}
```

I tried:

1. Wrapping it all in a try catch block
2. Chaining a `.catch()` method after the `.then()` method in the code

This doesn't solve the error. Any suggestions which might remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

```
    try returning sharp

    eg:
    function processText() {

        return sharp('./screenshot.png')
          ...
          ...
    }

If you are into ES6 format, check this out

const semiTransparentRedPng = await sharp({
  create: {
    width: 48,
    height: 48,
    channels: 4,
    background: { r: 255, g: 0, b: 0, alpha: 0.5 }
  }
})
  .png()
  .toBuffer();

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp
```